# Existence of a P-Complete language with space($\log\log n$) reduction

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, space-complexity

I have been reading and searching and I still cannot understand if there exists a language as following:

> Can a language be P-complete with respect to $\mathsf{Space}(\log \log n)$ reductions?

These reductions use some sort of transducer/transformer that is identical to a logarithmic transformer, except its working tape uses $O(\log\log n)$ symbols.

In other words, can the following happen?

1. There is a transformer with space $\log\log n$ that can reduce language A to B.
2. For some third language D:

   1. D belongs to class P
   2. For every language A in P there's a  $\mathsf{Space}(\log\log n)$ reduction to D.

I am really unsure about it. I mean, since the transformer can contain $O(\log\log n)$ symbols instead of $O(\log n)$ symbols, due to space constructibility, if $A \in \mathsf{Space}(\log n)$ then $A \not \in \mathsf{Space}(\log\log n)$? I mean if $g(n)=o(f(n))$ and $f(n)=\log\log n$, then $\mathsf{Space}(g(n)) \not \subseteq \mathsf{Space}(f(n))$, so to show such a language can exist there should be a language that can be polynomially reduced to some hard P-complete problem?

I don't understand it, especially the $\log\log n$, I think it affects the reducibility and therefore can cause a problem to create a valid transformer to show it can be reduced as needed.

Would very much appreciate if you could elaborate and show me if such language can really exist.